# Getting Clicked Item from ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

I am trying to get clicked item's string representation in Android ListActivity.My intention is get clicked item's string then convert it to speech by embedded tts service.The intent is fired by a long click on each item.Here is what i got so far.

> this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
>
> this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
>
> ```
>         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
>             int x=position;
>
>
>             try{
>                 switch (position)    {
>
>
>                     case 0:startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,Class.forName("Activity1")));
>                     case 1:startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,Class.forName("Acvivity2")));
>                     case 2:startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,Class.forName("Activity3")));
>
>
>                 }
>                 return true;
>             }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
>
>     });
>
>
>     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,program_names));
> ```

Above is long click method which is working.For a single click i thougth like this but it is not working:

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView lv,View v,int pos,long id){  
      super.onListItemClick(lv,v,pos,id);         
      String selected=(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(pos));
      tts.speak(selected,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);     
 }
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(onListItemClick);

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListItemClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
......

}
```

Comment: But i have a ListActivity,not a ListView.

Comment: Doesn't make much of a difference. ListView still works the same way. What you can do now is change the prototype of your function to the one I have given in my answer and it would work.

Comment: `this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
......

}`

Comment: Then how i can get "myList" from ListActivity.I tried this.getListView but it is not worked.

Comment: Forget `myList` since you are using ListActivity. Just do whatever you are doing for the LongClick. Simply replace that event handler with the prototype I gave in my answer.